# PHP module not built when compiling PHP 5.5.5

Tags: php, php-ini

I'm trying to build PHP 5.5.5 as an Apache module (on a Dreamhost VPS). I'm using this configure command:

```
'./configure'  '--prefix=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5' '--with-config-file-path=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5/etc/php5' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5/etc/php5' '--enable-so' '--bindir=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5/bin' '--enable-zip' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-mhash=/usr' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-curl=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5' '--with-gd' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-exif' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pear' '--with-gettext' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-openssl=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5' '--with-xsl' '--with-mcrypt=/home/stimulantvps/php/php5.5.5'
```

The build goes fine, but there is no .so file output anywhere that I can find.

bin/php does run from the command-line though, and the output of phpinfo() is here. https://gist.github.com/endquote/f57d510080eb44e9d818

Comment: Did you enable php mod in apache config and restart, after the build?

Comment: I don't think I can enable mod_php in apache if it hasn't been built. I think I need to do '--with-apache=/usr/local/dh/apache2/template/' or '--with-apxs=/usr/local/dh/apache2/template/sbin/apxs', but both are failing for different reasons. Might not be able to do this without rebuilding Apache too, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: Nah, you don't have to rebuild apache to get it to use php, just add the following to your httpd.conf: `LoadModule php5_module /path/to/libphp5.so`, mine is at `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`